# Update records in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I had like to update the `logdate` column for ALL records in a specific index. From what I have read so far, it seems that it is not possible? I am correct?

Here's a sample of a document:

```
{
            "_index": "logstash-01-2015",
            "_type": "ufdb",
            "_id": "AU__EvrALg15uxY1Wxf9",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "message": "2015-08-14 06:50:05 [31946] PASS  level2      10.249.10.70    level2     ads       http://ad.360yield.com/unpixel.... GET",
               "@version": "1",
               "@timestamp": "2015-09-24T11:17:57.389Z",
               "type": "ufdb",
               "file": "/usr/local/ufdbguard/logs/ufdbguardd.log",
               "host": "PROXY-DEV",
               "offset": "3983281700",
               "logdate": "2015-08-14T04:50:05.000Z",
               "status": "PASS",
               "group": "level2",
               "clientip": "10.249.10.70",
               "category": "ads",
               "url": "http://ad.360yield.com/unpixel....",
               "method": "GET",
               "tags": [
                  "_grokparsefailure"
               ]
            }
         }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "update"?  Change the value to some other string?  Convert it to a date object instead of a string?  Copy the value to @timestamp?  or ?

Comment: I had like to change the logdate field to another date for ALL documents. In MySQL, I would have done something like this:
`UPDATE logstash SET logdate= "2015-09-20T04:50:05.000Z"`
but it ElasticSearch it seems that I can only update one document by supplying its _id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, that is not possible.

There's been an open issue asking [Update by Query](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/2230) for long time, and I'm not sure it's going to be implemented anytime soon since it is very problematic for the underlying lucene engine. It requires deleting all documents and reindexing them.

An [Update by Query Plugin](https://github.com/yakaz/elasticsearch-action-updatebyquery) is available on github, but it's experimental and I never tried it.

**UPDATE 2018-05-02**

The original answer is quite old. [Update By Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html) is now supported.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [partial update API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html#_updates_with_a_partial_document).

To test it, I created a trivial index:

```
PUT /test_index
```

Then created a document:

```
PUT /test_index/doc/1
{
   "message": "2015-08-14 06:50:05 [31946] PASS  level2      10.249.10.70    level2     ads       http://ad.360yield.com/unpixel.... GET",
   "@version": "1",
   "@timestamp": "2015-09-24T11:17:57.389Z",
   "type": "ufdb",
   "file": "/usr/local/ufdbguard/logs/ufdbguardd.log",
   "host": "PROXY-DEV",
   "offset": "3983281700",
   "logdate": "2015-08-14T04:50:05.000Z",
   "status": "PASS",
   "group": "level2",
   "clientip": "10.249.10.70",
   "category": "ads",
   "url": "http://ad.360yield.com/unpixel....",
   "method": "GET",
   "tags": [
      "_grokparsefailure"
   ]
}
```

Now I can do a partial update on the document with:

```
POST /test_index/doc/1/_update
{
    "doc": {
        "logdate": "2015-09-25T12:20:00.000Z"
    }
}
```

If I retrieve the document:

```
GET /test_index/doc/1
```

I will see that the `logdate` property has been updated:

```
{
   "_index": "test_index",
   "_type": "doc",
   "_id": "1",
   "_version": 2,
   "found": true,
   "_source": {
      "message": "2015-08-14 06:50:05 [31946] PASS  level2      10.249.10.70    level2     ads       http://ad.360yield.com/unpixel.... GET",
      "@version": "1",
      "@timestamp": "2015-09-24T11:17:57.389Z",
      "type": "ufdb",
      "file": "/usr/local/ufdbguard/logs/ufdbguardd.log",
      "host": "PROXY-DEV",
      "offset": "3983281700",
      "logdate": "2015-09-25T12:20:00.000Z",
      "status": "PASS",
      "group": "level2",
      "clientip": "10.249.10.70",
      "category": "ads",
      "url": "http://ad.360yield.com/unpixel....",
      "method": "GET",
      "tags": [
         "_grokparsefailure"
      ]
   }
}
```

Here is the code I used to test it:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/236bf271df6d867f5f0c87eacab592e41d3095cf

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think I have not explained correctly. I have checked the update API but from what I can see is that you have to supply the _id field in order to run the update. In my case, I have like to run an update on all documents to make the 'logdate' the same.